# Low Pass Step and Low Pass Pulse sith Vextor Network Analyzer

Tags: rf, measurement, microwave, frequency-measurement, vna

I have an extremely basic question about time domain measurements with Vector Analyzer. It is something that is not explained in simple words in all datasheets/guides (maybe they think it is obvious and trivial).

Basically, with time domain settings, a VNA measures S parameters and finds its Fourier Transform, in order to get a time domain representation of them (S11(t), S12(t) etc).

Now, the Fourier Transform of a function is one and one only function (there is a unique correspondence between time and frequency domain). But with VNA we may set Low Pass Pulse or Low Pass Step modes, and the resulting function of time will be different. Why? And which mode should I use to find the correspondence impedance (for instance with the formula: Z(t) = ( 1+ S11(t)  )/ ( 1- S11(t) ) )?

Reference: [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://home.deib.polimi.it/svelto/didattica/materiale_didattico/materiale%2520didattico_MRF/MRF%2520Time%2520domain%2520reflectometry.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiU17qqtofnAhV1wAIHHbbjBHoQFjAOegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw1xzej2yY6-6SxKeOEmNgn8)

Comment: Calibration is done with steps for Open, Short and Zo then the medium such as PCB stripline Zo can be measured from s11 due to dielectric constant tolerance then strip widths are compensated by board shop.   For defects in cables any reflected pulse at time T indicates distance d=vT/2

Comment: But which is the difference between low pass step and low pass pulse mode? Why do they determine different S11(t) curves? S11(t) is a physical property of the DUT

Comment: THey only show the result of a step for difference loads . A pulse occurs from a short. The pulse rise time 10~90% determines 0.35/BW,  Zo is sqrt(L/C ) ratio which is also trace Width/gap ratio to gnd plane and Zo changes with that on p12, while L varies 0.5 ~ 1nH /mm C varies greater with trace width and gap

Comment: This is how PCB board shops test Zo on PCB and improve tolerances to 10% or less  for $100 about  20 years ago. "Electrical Zo Test" using test track or "coupon'  they add to verifiy Dk. outside your design. If you use a square wave, they only look at the step. response. for each